# Laravel- syntax error, unexpected ',' using str_replace

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code which is meant to turn  the value of a variable into a link by turning it to lowercase and then replacing all whitespaces with `-`

Here is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.base')
@section('pageTitle', 'Login')

@section('content')

Your search results are:<br><br>

@foreach($posts as $post)
    <a href="{{ strtolower(str_replace("",-, $post))}}">{{ $post }}</a><br>
@endforeach       

@endsection
```

But I get:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
syntax error, unexpected ',' (View: C:\xampp2\htdocs\mysite\resources\views\search\index.blade.php)
```

My qustion is different from [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)  beacuse it is a LARAVEL error not a php SYNTAX error!The solution to my question is supposed to be:`{!! strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $post)) !!}`.I was meant to write `{!!` rather than `{{` as the opening blade tags and I mean you cannot do anything like that in pure php.

Comment: You did not wrap the dash in speech marks. `<a href="{{ strtolower(str_replace(" ","-", $post))}}">{{ $post }}</a><br>`

Comment: `""` - is not a whitespace, `-` is not a dash, it is php __minus__.

Comment: @u_mulder I've gotten it now:`{!! str_replace('', '-', $post) !!}` sooo...... nobody cares if  `-` is not a dash, it is php minus

Comment: @u_mulder unblock my question pls.It is a laravel error not php and I'v already gotten the answer plsssssss.

Comment: Perhaps you could use Laravel's `Illuminate\Support\Str::slug()` helper.

Comment: @Thomas I have gotten the answer but u_mulder blocked by question or I would have posted the answer

Comment: @Titoxdboss Shouting really doesn't get you anywhere, and Laravel's a PHP framework. Your (now solved) issue was a PHP error, even if you wrote that bad PHP in a Laravel template.

Comment: @ceejayoz I wasn't shouting.Why did u say that?

Comment: @Titoxdboss Your now-deleted comment was IN ALL CAPS, which is generally considered "shouting" on the Internet.

Comment: @ceejayoz but no answer on that page could have solved my error

Comment: @Titoxdboss The exception you posted IS actually a PHP error (missing quotes around the dash/minus), even if it's used inside a blade template. Using `{!!` also shouldn't have any effect as long as you don't output anything that can get HTML encoded (which I don't think you are). So you should switch back to `{{ }}` [for security](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data) if possible. And please try to be polite, even if others sometimes aren't.